# How to .zfproject.xml reorganization?

Tags: zend-framework

How do I manually updated after the installation .zfproject.xml?

Answer (score 0):

**.zfproject.xml**  keeps track off the changes made to the project anytime you use **Zend_Tool** (**ZF.bat** or **ZF.sh**). You can edit it antime you want in any text editor, however the results when you next use Zend_Tool maybe unpredictable.